# Cannot add a condition shopping basket price rule, no options or dropdown magento backend

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I have never come across this before, it works fine on both of the other two magento stores I manage.

This store has been running for over a year with no issues in the backend. However today for the first time, rather than a % discount, I tried to add a fixed one to find that there I cannot add an action. Regardless of browser that I use, clicking on 'ALL', 'TRUE' or the Green Plus does absolutely nothing - in other stores it works perfectly.

Magento V1.7.0.2

Screenshot here
[image: Magento no ability to edit conditions on shopping basket price rule]

This is the error:

```
TypeError: ({initialize:(function (parent, newChildUrl){
        this.parent = $(parent);
        this.newChildUrl  = newChildUrl;
        this.shownElement = null;
        this.updateElement = null;
        this.chooserSelectedItems = $H({});
        this.readOnly = false;

        var elems = this.parent.getElementsByClassName('rule-param');
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            this.initParam(elems[i]);
        }
    }), setReadonly:(function (readonly){
        this.readOnly = readonly;
        var elems = this.parent.getElementsByClassName('rule-param-remove');
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            var element = elems[i];
                if (this.readOnly) {
                    element.hide();
                } else {
                    element.show();
                }
        }

        var elems = this.parent.getElementsByClassName('rule-param-new-child');
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            var element = elems[i];
```

Google chrome inspector is showing:

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 7ae86150a079d1644bc06caeec8fc3ef.js:20556(anonymous function)

Comment: Check the error logs for an error and post back, or use an inspector when on the page to monitor the ajax request that gets fired off when you click the + button and see what the response is and if there is an error that comes back in the response for the ajax request.

Comment: Replied in orignal message, if you could take a look that would be great.

Comment: There is no Ajax call according to firebug.

Comment: Ah ok. The ajax request gets fired off after you have selected an option which you are not getting displayed, so no ajax for you just yet. There must be some sort of javascript error occurring which then fires the code you have posted above? The above code is the code for when the error occurs, but there must be an actual error happening somewhere with JS. Been a while since I used firebug as use chromes inspector to debug, but it must capturing the actual JS error somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I did think it might be something along them lines. However the only error occurring is from above, which is located in a .js file (that is merged/combined with all the rest with Magento to increase load times).

Comment: Also to add, I checked the error it has given above against the same code on another magento installation working fine and the code is exactly the same for the section showing as 'error'.

Comment: Chrome is showing: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 7ae86150a079d1644bc06caeec8fc3ef.js:20556(anonymous function)

Comment: Fixed, magento combining the .js files was causing the error.

Comment: So there is no real fix for this? Except disabling the .js combination which cuts in performance...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and although I'm unsure of the source of the problem, it seems to be caused when js files are merged.

In System > Configuration > Developer
Set 'Merge JavaScript Files' to 'No'

Then you should be able to add the price conditions, then just re-merge once complete.